# How can I prevent cropping on a mirrored external screen which happens to have the same pixel sizes as my built in laptop screen

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have a Lenovo W530 laptop. It has a 1920x1080 display (according to `xrandr`). The integrated NVIDIA Graphics is activated in the BIOS of the laptop. There is a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-prime.conf` and its content is

```
# DO NOT EDIT. AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED BY gpu-manager

Section "OutputClass"
Identifier "Nvidia Prime"
MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
Driver "nvidia"
Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
Option "PrimaryGPU" "Yes"
ModulePath "/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

Also I have another display which is connected to the DP2 of the docking station (there is a DP-to HDMI adapter to actually connect the other display). According to `xrandr`, the other display also has the same 1920x1080 resolution. But the shown display is cropped, see below.
`xrandr -q` tells me (the actual size of the other display is returned wrong, but the returned aspect ratio is ok):

```
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 392mm
EDID: 
    00ffffffffffff0034a996a201010101
    00180103808048780adaffa3584aa229
    17494b21080031404540614081800101
    010101010101023a80d072382d40102c
    4580ba882100001e023a801871382d40
    582c4500ba882100001e000000fc0050
    616e61736f6e69632d54560a000000fd
    00173d0f440f000a202020202020015a
    020322f24d9f90140520212213041203
    16072309070168030c001000b8260fe2
    004b011d80d0721c1620102c2580ba88
    2100009e011d8018711c1620582c2500
    ba882100009e011d00bc52d01e20b828
    5540ba882100001e662156aa51001e30
    468f3300ba882100001e000000000000
    000000000000000000000000000000bb
CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
BorderDimensions: 4 
    supported: 4
Border: 0 0 0 0 
    range: (0, 65535)
SignalFormat: TMDS 
    supported: TMDS
ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
ConnectorNumber: 3 
_ConnectorLocation: 3 
non-desktop: 0 
    supported: 0, 1
LVDS-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
EDID:
    00ffffffffffff0030aeb24000000000
    0113010380221378ea2135ad5037aa24
    11505400000001010101010101010101
    0101010101014c368082703832403c30
    aa0058c1100000183f2d808270383240
    3c30aa0058c1100000180000000f00d1
    0932d109281b190006af5634000000fe
    004231353648573031205634200a00d6
PRIME Synchronization: 0
    supported: 0, 1
scaling mode: Full aspect
    supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
link-status: Good
    supported: Good, Bad
CONNECTOR_ID: 67
    supported: 67
non-desktop: 0
    range: (0, 1)
```

However, the other display through  is cropped by

- ca 14 lines from the top     and ca 16 lines from the bottom,
- ca 37 columns from the left  and ca 40 columns to the right.

(Determining the exact number of missing pixels is not very easy).

**Which `xrandr` commands are necessary to configure the display on this Panasonic TV set such that no cropping happens.**

Or

do I have to use `xrandr` commands to effectively reduce the size of the laptop screen by those lines and columns to be used while the other screen is connected? **Which would be the right commands to achieve this?**

Comment: Did you try to locate a setting called "1:1 pixel mapping" on your TV, which should be ***enabled*** for the current source (HDMI input)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FedonKadifeli' question led me to the solution: On the Panasonic TV set under Option settings for Image I had to enable the option "1080p Pixel Direkt".

Obviously the interpolation done by the TV set reproduced the original image quality on the 1080p (HDMI) input.

So this was not really a Linux problem but rather one as known under the keyword overscan,

The image looked much sharper than it did before and it fits exactly to my laptop screen. Thanks for the trick!